# Facebook Profile getName() on Android always returning null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

My Facebook Login Activity if it helps:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "user_friends");
        final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
            return;
        }
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // Callback registration
                loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean isLoggedIn() {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        return accessToken != null;
    }
}
```

**and the code I'm using to attempt to get someone's first name from their ID:**

```
new Profile(creatorId, null, null, null, null, null).getFirstName()
```

I have tried the getFirstName() call shown here in addition to getName() and both always return null. I thought having "public_profile" in my requested Facebook permissions would allow me to get someone's name in this way if they have authorized my app while logging in through Facebook. However, I did not always have "public_profile" in my requested Facebook permissions, but I have forced all users to re-login through Facebook to my app with this current code and permissions, so I thought this would fix this problem. Nevertheless, this function keeps returning null and I'm not sure why.

**Also, creatorId may be the FB ID of a different user than the currently logged in FB user.** (They will have authorized+used the app in the past, just not the currently logged in user on that Android device).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that a Graph Request is necessary, even for public profile information. Here is the Graph Request I used to get the first name for a certain Facebook ID, creatorId:

```
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            creatorId,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("creatorId's first name:", response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "id,first_name");
    request.setParameters(params);
    request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this code.
>   please change your GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() interface

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),                                
new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                                    try {
                                                                                    Log.e(TAG,"id"+user.optString("id"));                                            
                                        Log.e(TAG,"id"+user.optString("first_name"));


                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();`
```